# How to add request data to support email using Illuminate\Http\Request;

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, laravel-5

I created a "Ask for support" contact form (using a modal) in my app. What would be the best/cleanest way to add/attach a dump of the `$request` variable? (PHP's global variables, session data, ...) Because I believe this data can help me a lot to debug.

What I tried:

SupportController:

```
public function send(Request $request)
    {
        Mail::send('emails.support', ['request' => $request], function ($message) use ($request) {
            $message->from($request->user()->email, $request->user()->name);
            $message->subject(trans('Support request'));
        });

        $request->session()->flash('flash_message', __('Message sent!'));
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

emails.support.blade

`{{ print_r($request) }}`

But I get a memory size exhausted error message (even after I changed the limit to 1GB).

So there might be a better way to do this. Maybe also a more readable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't dump the entire request object, instead pick and choose what you find necessary to be helpful for debugging. For example:

```
All:
@foreach($request->all() as $key => $val)
   {{ $key }} = {{ $val }}
@endforeach
<hr>
Route Name: {{ $request->route()->getName() }}
Route Action: {{ $request->route()->getAction() }}
Route Method: {{ $request->route()->getMethod() }}
<hr>
Headers:
@foreach($request->headers->all() as $key => $val)
   {{ $key }} = {{ $val }}
@endforeach
```

Etc, etc..

Or you can use Guzzle's [str](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/master/src/functions.php#L17) method to serialize a request or response object.